# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'num' not found

Tags: jsp

Error:

[image: this is the error code]

Code:

```jsp
<%
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";    
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    Connection con=null;
    ResultSet rst=null;
        ResultSet rst1=null;
        ResultSet rst2=null;
        ResultSet rst3=null;        
    Statement stmt=null;
        Statement stmt1=null;
        Statement stmt2=null;
        Statement stmt3=null;

    try{
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/company?user=root&password=root";
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        stmt=con.createStatement();
                System.out.println("success");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("failed");
    }
%>


<%   

        rst = stmt.executeQuery("select max(num) from invoicename;");
    if (rst.next()) {
        String str = rst.getString("num");

        rst1 = stmt.executeQuery("Select sum(price) from invoices where invoiceno='" + str + "';");
        if (rst1.next()) {
            int s = rst1.getInt(1);
            if (rst1.wasNull()) {
                s = 0;
            }
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into invoice values('" + str + "',curdate(),curtime(),'" + s + "');");
        }
    }
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into invoicename values();");



%>
```

Error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'num' not found

I can't find the problem in the above code. The error has been attached in the image.

Comment: Note that the first version of this question was very spammy, and makes it worthy of downvotes if not closure. Please write your questions with care and effort, and avoid txtspk and begging. Note that if writing real words is too much trouble, Stack Overflow may not be for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have the line `String str = rst.getString("num");` but the query you have done does not return any column named `num` (you are querying `max(num)`). Either you just try to get the result from the first (and only) column:

```
String str = rst.getString(1);
```

or you change th query to return the result with a name and then reference that name when you want to get the result:

```
rst = stmt.executeQuery("select max(num) as maxnum from invoicename;");
if (rst.next()) {
    String str = rst.getString("maxnum");
```